# Looping through characters in a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, loops, character

I'm busy working on past exam papers in preparation for a Visual Basic exam. I need help with the following question which I'm stuck with.

> Write a function procedure to calculate the number of times the characters "e", "f" and "g" appears in a string

I tried to write the psuedo code and came up with the following.

```
Loop through each individual character in the string
If the character = "e","f" or "g" add 1 to number of characters
Exit loop 
Display total in messagebox
```

How do I loop through individual characters in a string (using a `for` loop) and how do I count the number of times a specific character appears in a string?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer greatly depends on what you’ve already learned in your course work and which functions you are supposed to use.

But in general, looping over the characters in a string is as easy as this:

```
Dim s As String = "test"

For Each c As Char in s
    ' Count c
Next
```

As for counting, simply have separate counter variables (`eCount As Integer` etc.) for each character and increment them when `c` equals that character – obviously that approach doesn’t scale well once you increase the number of characters to count. This can be solved by maintaining a dictionary of the relevant characters but I’m guessing that this is too advanced for your exercise.

Comment: Thanx Konrad really appreciate your input

Comment: For Each may only iterate over a collection object or an array (VBA).

Comment: @AndersLindén True but the question was about VB.NET, not VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Looping through a string is simple: a string can be treated as a list of characters, which can be looped.

```
Dim TestString = "ABCDEFGH"
for i = 0 to TestString.length-1
debug.print(teststring(i))
next
```

even easier would be a for..each loop, but sometimes a for i loop is better

For counting the numbers I would use a dictionary
Like this:

```
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)
        dict.Add("e"c, 0)
Beware: a dictionary can only hold ONE item of the key - that means, adding another "e" would cause an error.
each time you encounter the char you want, call something like this:
        dict.Item("e"c) += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use (or you want to learn)  Linq, you can use `Enumerable.GroupBy`.

Assuming your question is the text you want to search:

```
Dim text = "H*ow do i loop through individual characters in a string (using a for loop) and how do I count the number of times a specific character appears in a string?*"
Dim charGroups = From chr In text Group By chr Into Group

Dim eCount As Int32 = charGroups.Where(Function(g) g.chr = "e"c).Sum(Function(g) g.Group.Count)
Dim fCount As Int32 = charGroups.Where(Function(g) g.chr = "f"c).Sum(Function(g) g.Group.Count)
Dim gCount As Int32 = charGroups.Where(Function(g) g.chr = "g"c).Sum(Function(g) g.Group.Count)
```