# Replace every single character in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to make an "encryption system" so every single letter is replaced with another letter.

Let's say we have

```
Dim encrypt As String = "hi"
encrypt = Replace(encrypt, "h", "i")
encrypt = Replace(encrypt, "i", "j")
```

Instead of becoming `ij` so it can be decrypted to `hi`, it becomes `jj` because `i` is already encrypted, but it encrypts it again.

What can I do?

Comment: Replace in one pass. Create a stringbuilder, loop over existing characters and add each replacing character to the stringbuilder.

Comment: umm wat? I don't know what you mean

Comment: Look at every character just once, not over and over again like you do now.

Comment: I don't know how... Can't you show me on the example I gave earlier?

Comment: [Looping through characters in a string in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13251344/11683). [`StringBuilder.Append` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.append%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i still don't get it

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvoting this... Even though it's a simple solution, I think the question is well-written.

Comment: OP: The answer in the question GSerg linked shows you how to loop through every character.

Comment: @VisualVincent I assume the reasons are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249375/replace-every-single-character-in-visual-basic#comment60128527_36249375, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249375/replace-every-single-character-in-visual-basic#comment60128583_36249375, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249375/replace-every-single-character-in-visual-basic#comment60128677_36249375 and "This question does not show any research effort" tooltip that appears when you hover over the downvote arrow.

Comment: @GSerg : Can't hover with my phone. ;)

Comment: @GSerg actually that's the description of the downvote button, if you hover the upvote it says the basic opposite of that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method to achieve your task ([runnable example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Ylxac)):

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System

Public Class Program

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim test As String = "Hi there"
        Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each chr As char In test ' Here you iterate every char in your string
            Select Case chr
                Case "H"
                    sb.Append("i") ' Here you replace your char and append to final result
                    Exit Select
                Case "i"C
                    sb.Append("p")
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    sb.Append(chr)
                    Exit Select

            End Select
        Next

        Dim result = sb.ToString()

        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Instead another simple method would use a Dictionary to map your chars, it is better because you don't have to write a loooong `select/case` statement ([runnable example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PGEhUl))

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System

Public Class Program

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        ' Here you can declare you char mapping
        Dim mapping As New Dictionary(Of Char, Char)() From { _
            {"H"C, "i"C}, _
            {"i"C, "p"C} _
        }

        ' test input
        Dim test As String = "Hi there"
        Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        ' Here you iterate every char in your string
        For Each chr As Char In test

            ' if a char is mapped
            Dim value As Char
            If mapping.TryGetValue(chr, value) Then
                ' append mapped char to final result
                sb.Append(value)
            Else
                ' otherwise append the original char
                sb.Append(chr)

            End If
        Next

        Dim result As String = sb.ToString()

        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
End Class
```