# Convert all words from text file to UpperCase using cmd or vbsscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a text file called C:\Test.txt. I would like to convert all words inside the text file to UpperCases using cmd. Could you please help me?

I tried with

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "line=!line:%%b=%%b!"
   )
   echo !line!
)
```

but i do not see where to put the location of the test.txt file

Comment: *yourbatchfilename* filenametoprocess should process the file

Comment: I do not understand you. How is it going to process the text file called test.txt in C:\ if i do not set the location somewhere or give it to some variable. Apologies, I am new to the cmd and vbs scripts

Comment: `%1` means "the first parameter". So you give the filename to your batchfile as a parameter: `yourbatchfile.bat "C:\Test.txt"`, then  `%1` will hold `C:\Test.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082) already pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372506/convert-all-words-from-text-file-to-uppercase-using-cmd-or-vbsscript#comment75749728_44372506), `%1` constitutes an [argument reference](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) that points to the first command line argument. Therefore, supposing your batch file is called `upper-case.bat` and your text file is `C:\test.txt`, you must call your batch file like this:

```cmd
upper-case.bat C:\test.txt
```

However, in case your test file contains white-spaces or special characters in its path, like `C:\test file.txt`, for example, you must put it in between quotation marks, like this:

```cmd
upper-case.bat "C:\test file.txt"
```

For your batch file to not fail, you must modify it like this to handle quoted arguments properly:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "line=!line:%%b=%%b!"
   )
   echo(!line!
)
```

Instead of `%1` I wrote `"%~1"`, which first removes potential surrounding quotes (`~`), then places quotes around the result. That way, we always have exactly a pair of quotes. To make [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) handle quotes correctly, so to not treat the quoted file path as a literal string, I added its `usebackq` option.

Note that `for /F` ignores empty lines, hence such become lost. It also ignores lines beginning with a semicolon (`;`), because of its default `eol` option; to avoid that, replace `"usebackq delims="` by the odd-looking unquoted syntax `usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=` (you cannot state `"usebackq delims= eol="`, because this would define `"` as the `eol` character).

To prevent [`echo`](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) from returning `ECHO is {on|off}.` in case white-space-only lines are encountered, I replaced the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> behind `echo` by `(`, because this is the only way to safely return the given string.

By the way, to write the output to another text file, use [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), like in the following command line:

```cmd
upper-case.bat "C:\test.txt" > "C:\return.txt"
```

Regard that you must specify a different file than the input file.

Answer (score 0):

After loading text file as a variable, you could loop throught each char with 
    foreach
 and check the Asci value (msgbox Asc("A")).
if asci code is between 97 and 122 ("a" and "z") , remove 32 ("A" is 65 and "a" is 97  ---->  "z" is 122 and "Z" is 90).

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx

and : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251344/looping-through-characters-in-a-string-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

Where `%1` is the first parameter, means the **InputFile** and `%2` is the second parameter, means the **OutputFile**

```bat
@echo off
set "InputFile=C:\Test.txt"
set "OuputFile=C:\UpCaseTest.txt"
If Exist "%OuputFile%" Del "%OuputFile%"
Call :Convert2UpCase "%InputFile%" "%OuputFile%"
Start "" "%OuputFile%"
Exit /b
::**********************************************************************
:Convert2UpCase <InputFile> <OutputFile>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('Type %1') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "line=!line:%%b=%%b!"
   )
   echo !line!>>%2
)
::**********************************************************************
```

Answer (score -1):

File: fucase.vbs

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt", 1, True)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  WScript.Echo UCase(f.ReadLine)
Loop

f.Close
```

Batch (or cmd) call:

```
cscript fucase.vbs
```